# Install/deploy/run Symfony 4 on shared hosting

Tags: deployment, hosting, production, symfony4

I'm pretty new to Symfony and looking for a way to make it useful on our shared hosting environment. We want to create a small api, but first we want to see if we get SF4 to work on our shared environment.

I have an SSH account and they opened a port for us.

First of all I create a new project:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton sf
```

Secondly I install the server:

```
composer require server
```

At last I start the server:

```
./bin/console server:run *:3000
```

After this I receive a message everything is running:

```
 [OK] Server listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000                                                                          


 // Quit the server with CONTROL-C.                                                                                    

PHP 7.1.3 Development Server started at Mon Jan 22 19:41:50 2018
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
Document root is /home/MyUser/public_html/testapp/sf/public
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

When I browse to my http://my-url:3000, the page doesn't load.

Has anyone a solution for me?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you ping each other ? any firewall or iptable blocking the connection on `:3000` ?

Comment: Looks like you can only acces it from the local server... Like I said: I'm new. So, any suggestions are welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the setup so I don't need to start the server.

See [Symfony 4 404 Page not found on all routes except root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449503/symfony-4-404-page-not-found-on-all-routes-except-root/48449998#48449998)