# Symfony 4 404 Page not found on all routes except root

Tags: symfony, routes, http-status-code-404

I have installed symfony 4 on my shared hosting.
My structure is like this:

```
ROOT
  |
  |-- public_html
        |
        |-- tst
  |-- tst
        |
        |-- bin
        |-- config
        |-- src
        |-- translations
        |-- var
        |-- vendor
        |-- composer.json
        |-- composer.lock
        |-- binsymfony.lock
```

I moved index.php from the public folder to the public_html/tst folder and changed the paths inside that file to match the new structure:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../tst/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Now, when running http://mysite/tst, I get the homepage of the site as expected. But when I try another route (other than "/"), I always receive  a 404 page not found.

Does this have something to do with privileges of am I missing something?

I figured this one out myself, but if someone tell me how to deploy a Symfony 4 application to a shared hosting, please tell me! I think other people will like this too...

Comment: Probably missing the `.htaccess` containing the RewriteRules.

Comment: What needs to be in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create symlik for Public. The method you try can lead to problems.

```
# Enter Directory Root
cd /root_dir

# Create Symlink
ln -s public_html tst/public
```

Comment: Doesn't that raise problems with the site that is located directly in public_html? The website is in /public_html and the new project needs to be under /public_html/tst.

Comment: I moved whole project to a directory at the same level as public_html, added a symlink, but same thing as before.
Root of project is working an showing up on the screen, but other routes are not working, resulting in a 404 Page not found...